# Truffle Compile failing, ParserError: Expected token LParen got Identifier function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

truffle compile fails with the following error:

Error parsing /Users/rdelrosario/ron-eth-pet-shop/test/TestAdoption.sol: ParsedContract.sol:19:14: ParserError: Expected token LParen got 'Identifier'function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {

Code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

  // Testing the adopt() function
  function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
    uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

    uint expected = 8;

    Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");

    // Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
      // Expected owner is this contract
      address expected = this;

      address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

      Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");

    // Testing retrieval of all pet owners
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public {
      // Expected owner is this contract
      address expected = this;

      // Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
      address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

      Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors don't lie. Your parentheses are mismatched.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

  // Testing the adopt() function
  function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
    uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);

    uint expected = 8;

    Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

  // Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
  function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
    // Expected owner is this contract
    address expected = this;

    address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);

    Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

  // Testing retrieval of all pet owners
  function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public {
    // Expected owner is this contract
    address expected = this;

    // Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
    address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

    Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tests passed, compiled successfully.